# How to trigger an UpdatePanel by a TextBox control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, triggers, updatepanel, ajax.net

Consider the following code:

```
<label>Search:</label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="search" ClientIDMode="Static" OnKeyUp="$('#searchButton').click();" /><asp:Button runat="server" ID="searchButton" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="true" PageSize="20"
            Width="400" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="searchButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The button will trigger an update of the panel. I wanted to trigger an update by a keydown of the search field, so I'm 'faking' it with a jQuery statement that clicks the button. I'm wondering... there must be a better way... right!?

Comment: May be this would help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009086/how-to-make-an-asp-net-textbox-fire-its-ontextchanged-event-fire-in-an-ajax-upd

Comment: @Kiran the search field is outside the update panel, which makes it a tat differenct that question 1009086, because if I use an auto submit the page will be submitted. Maybe Remy is right and should I write my own control for it...

Comment: Yes I too agree.As I am also right now working on the same thing may be he his right.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker, as such I don't see any issue in faking click on the trigger. The UpdatePanel model works by capturing form submit - the element that has caused submit is checked against the map maintained of valid submit triggers. Unless you want to rely on internal workings of UpdatePanel, IMO, faking trigger click seems to be a nice non-intrusive solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to refresh your updatepanel without the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function refreshPanel() {
        __doPostBack('<%= updatePanel.UniqueID %>', '');
    }

</script>
<label>Search:</label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="search"  
                ClientIDMode="Static" OnKeyUp="refreshPanel();" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
```

You just need to give your updatepanel an ID (updatePanel here)

Execute that code on a keyup or whenever you are ready for it.

Comment: It submits the page. I would like to do a AJAX post back that causes no page refresh.

Comment: Turns out the <% %> can't be set to the OnKeyUp property :(

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: Just put the code in a seperate function and call that function in your keyup.

Answer (score 1):

The link is a bit outdates, but should pretty much do what you want:
http://remy.supertext.ch/2007/06/see-search-results-as-you-type-an-aspnet-ajax-control/

Comment: Not that I know, but my code does pretty much what you need, no?

Comment: Yeah. I would like to merge the DelayedSubmitExtender and the TextBox into one of control, so it can work together as a trigger-option.