# UpdatePanel ASP.NET TextBox (Like Google search box)

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, updatepanel

First I would like to point out that I have use Javascript and ASP.Net to work around. However, I heard that UpdatePanel and TextBox (char by char filter). I belived this much faster as I can save a lot time doing rendering.

I tried to followed 
[How to trigger an UpdatePanel by a TextBox control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249152/how-to-trigger-an-updatepanel-by-a-textbox-control)

But the it wont work. Here is the example

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = cmd;
        JB.CommandResponse response = JB.Master.DataBase.ExecuteQuery(query); //database
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView_product.DataSource = response.Get_DataRecords();
            GridView_product.DataBind();
            TextBox_search.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "refresh()");
            return; 
        }

        response = JB.Master.DataBase.ExecuteQuery(query); //database
        query += " and code_p like '%" + TextBox_search.Text + "%' or " +
        "name_p like '%" + TextBox_search.Text + "%'";

        GridView_product.DataSource = response.Get_DataRecords();
        GridView_product.DataBind();          
    }
```

//Aspx

```
<script>
var refresh = function () {
  __doPostBack('<%= myUpdatePanel.ClientID %>', '');
};
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_search" runat="server" CssClass="textbox left"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="myUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Always">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView_product" runat="server" CssClass="gridview"   ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"></asp:GridView>

  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox_search" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Initially DO NOT use string concatenation in your query USE parameters.

Comment: Why don't try to use PageMethods and on keyup call your method and get your data?

Comment: Hi, Yup I have use PageMethods, and use Javascript with Json. Just that I believed using UpdatePanel and Postback is better and easier.

Comment: As for the query not to worry so much. I am calling my dll libraries of course I have I have a build in parameter function. Just that I dont use it often that all

Comment: Ok then, i have just to mention it just for your protection. :) Pagemethods, javascript and json is more clear.

Comment: Beside clearer to understand is there any reason why Pagemethod is better?  Anyway just 1 question why string concatenation is not recommend? Aside from typo error ?

Comment: I cannot think other reason beside clearer to understand. As for using string concat and not parameters see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection