# Full postback instead of partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I need to update an `UpdatePanel` on `onkeyup` event of textbox, I've writed this code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="elenco.aspx.vb" Inherits="GestioneCommesse.WebForm1" EnableEventValidation = "false"%>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chc_tutti_anni" runat="server" Text="Cerca in tutti gli anni" AutoPostBack="true" style="top: 151px; left: 10px; position: absolute; " />
   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_commessa" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript:__doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.UniqueID %>','')" style="top: 90px; left: 250px; position: absolute; width: 199px"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
        <ContentTemplate>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chc_tutti_anni" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is that the `javascript:__doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.UniqueID %>','')`  performs a full page postback, instead of postpack only the UpdatePanel.

On event `CheckedChange` everything is fine.

I've also tried this line:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_commessa" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript:__doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.UniqueID %>','')" autopostback="true" style="top: 90px; left: 250px; position: absolute; width: 199px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Someone could help me?

------EDIT------

I've just tried this solution, same problem
[How to trigger an UpdatePanel by a TextBox control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249152/how-to-trigger-an-updatepanel-by-a-textbox-control)

------EDIT------

The question still unsolved, please help me.

Comment: How you know that full page postback was performed?

Comment: @Fabio Because all page is refreshed, not only UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

Your `textbox` should be inside `UpdatePanel->ContentTemplate`.

Comment: Yes, but textbox loses focus.

Comment: I've tried to put textbox inside updatePanel, but I can't trigger the UpdatePanel to onkeyup event. Could help me?