# check if username is available or taken

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a simple application in ASP.NET C# and using MS SQL Server 2008. I need to register all visitor users to my site. For that users will have to fill a form.
The problem is that as the user enters the **Desired Username** field, I should be able to check in background whether another user has already taken that **username**. I will have to fire an sql select query to check for the availability.

Currently I am using the `TextBoxName_TextChanged` method but it does not work in realtime. It works only on a postback. The code is that follows:

```
protected void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox3.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                availability.Text = "";
                return;
            }

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select username from users where username='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "users");
            if (ds.Tables["users"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                availability.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                availability.Text = "Not Available";
            }
            else
            {
                availability.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                availability.Text = "Available";
            }

        }
```

Please  suggest me something as all I searched on web was about PHP, Not ASP.NET

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <table cellpadding="5" class="style1"> 
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Username" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
            <td style="border:0px none #FF0000;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="175px" 
                    CssClass="input-control" ForeColor="Black" ontextchanged="TextBox3_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3"></td>
            <td style="border:0px none #FF0000;"> 

                <asp:Label ID="availability" runat="server" Width="175px" CssClass="text" Text="availability"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Password" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
            <td style="border:0px none #FF0000;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="175px" TextMode="Password" CssClass="input-control" ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Email" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
            <td style="border:0px none #FF0000;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="175px" CssClass="input-control" ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td class="style3">

            <td style="width:30%; text-align: right; padding: 10px; border:none;">
                <div class="button-set" data-role="button-set">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" class="active bg-color-red" Text="Sign Up" />
                </div>
        </tr>
        </table></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

Update:

Following Everybody's comments and answers I have achieved this much with a little problem shown in this screenshot: [image: Screenshot]
Don't know why there are another label with status and the **availability_status** stays as it is. Please help.

Comment: Use the persons email much less likely to be used twice.

Comment: please suggest a solution, not alternatives. I might feel the need to check for existing emails also, so that nobody duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're update panel is not well formatted. You need to put "availability" label into update panel, then set a trigger for the username text box and then set the event name.
something like :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="availability" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" >                                         
    </asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox3" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

you also nee to set  AutoPostBack="True" in your text box. 
I think it shall work.

Comment: Could not find an event named 'TextBox3_TextChanged' on associated control 'TextBox3' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Comment: double check the event name! event name in trigger must be "TextChanged" alone.

Comment: Ok, its working. But it updates the Label only when the TextBox loses focus. Is there anyway so that the Label Updates with each character I type?

Comment: Postback by default only send when you loose focus on textbox, if you want to fire the event whenever a character is typing, you will need to send postback when a character types. I never done that before, but hell yeah, it's possible. let me work on it. takes some time sorry. hint: I think we must use javascript to manually send postbacks.

Comment: Check if these are helpfull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758240/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-postback-on-keyup      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009086/how-to-make-an-asp-net-textbox-fire-its-ontextchanged-event-fire-in-an-ajax-upd

Comment: Well thanks for the links, they helped and I have almost achieved what I wanted. But one small problem, it displays "Available" and "Not Available" separately and doesn't alter my label text! The label text remains as it is. Why? 
_Also note that, I have taken out my textbox from the UpdatePanel! Kept my label inside it, AsyncTriggers in place and JS for postbacks on KeyUp. Also set AutoPostback=false._

Comment: Please check the screenshot added and help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire off your request via AJAX. Hook up to the 'changed' event of the text box client side and trigger it from there - best option would be to use jQuery e.g.

```
<script text="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchTimer;
    ...
    $('TextBox3').change(function() {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        clearTimer(searchTimer);
        searchTimer = setTimeout(1000, function() {
            $.get('findUsers', { userName: searchTerm }, function(response) {
                // process successful response
            }).error(function(error) {
                // process error response
            });
        });
    });
});
<script>

<table>
    ...
    <input type="text" id="TextBox3" />
</table>
```

The above would fire a request to an API call "findUsers" 1 second after every text change. This is to avoid sending unnecessary requests when the user is typing as you only want to send the request when the user has finished.

Comment: How can I do that? I think that is what I want, something that keeps firing sql queries as I type in that TextBox.

Comment: @SamarthArgarwal I was in the middle of adding an example, I am on my mobile so not quite as easy to type/formatting code!

Comment: Which language is this example in?

Comment: It's Javascript, it's also using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which makes writing client side AJAX requests simple (as per the example)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.
I don't feel like understanding it at all! I have a ASP.NET project. Where do I put it?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you an example of where you would place the code. However, if you don't know anything about client-side programming I suggest you read a bit more into it...

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me a little more about it? Like what things do I need to replace? What is findUsers? What should I replave it with in my code?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal I suggest you go *research* client-side programming as it's a pretty large topic...not suitable for an SO comment. Don't take the example I have provided literally it was for demonstration purposes - you won't have an API call `findUsers` that was just an example. What you would need to do is create your own API call which you can query to give you what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Does the textbox have AutoPostBack="true" ? 
You will certainly need to add an UpdatePanel aroud your textbox in order to prevent the full page load.

Comment: I added an update panel but it still refreshes full page as soon as TextBox loses focus.

Comment: Can you add the part of code where you declare the UpdatePanel and the textbox ?

Comment: Your UpdatePanel is not well formed. It's closed two times.

Comment: It should be something like this :
    `<asp:UpdatePanel>
     <ContentTemplate> <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" ... /> </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>`

Comment: The Label + the Textbox need to be in the update panel. Just put all your form in it, it's easier.

Comment: Let me try. I'll post back in a while.

Comment: Ok, its working. But it updates the Label only when the TextBox loses focus. Is there anyway so that the Label Updates with each character I type?

Comment: I don't think so. TextBox doens't have an OnKeyPress event. To do what you want you would need to use @James approch with javascript calling some code in your server.

Comment: I have almost achieved what I wanted. But one small problem, it displays "Available" and "Not Available" separately and doesn't alter my label text! The label text remains as it is. Why? Also note that, I have taken out my textbox from the UpdatePanel! Kept my label inside it, AsyncTriggers in place and JS for postbacks on KeyUp

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working, Thanks to all those who took interest and tried.
The solution is to make PostBack on every OnkeyUp event, and this can be done using JS.

The markup is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="175px" 
                    CssClass="input-control" ForeColor="Black" onkeyup="RefreshUpdatePanel();" ontextchanged="TextBox3_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate><asp:Label ID="availability" runat="server" Width="175px" CssClass="text" Text="availability_label"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox3" EventName="TextChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
```

The Javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function RefreshUpdatePanel() {
          __doPostBack('<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>', '');
      };
</script>
```

And the code for checking if the username exists or not is written inside the

> TextBox3_TextChanged() Method. It worked.

Answer (score -2):

I recently built this function you can try it out by yourself.

```
public bool IsExist(string name, string pass)  /// in your case you only need to save the textbox on a string variable
    {
        string sql = "select * from Users where UName='" + name + "' and Pass='" + pass + "'"; ; 
        DataSet ds = General.GetData(sql); // General class has function called GetData which obviouslly gets the data of the required SQL information.
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The Op isn't asking *how* to query their DB he is asking how to query it without having to do a post back.